# Cannot Install TOR on windows - Installer integrity failed

Tags: windows, tor-install

I downloaded the Tor installer and ran it on my Windows. An error message pops up saying installer integrity failed. How can I fix it?

P.s - I have unblocked it by going to properties.

Comment: Have you tried verifying the GnuPG signature of the file? There is some really *rare* cases of file damage when you download files from internet. See more about it here: <https://www.torproject.org/signing-keys.html>

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Tor installer is corrupted.
I recommend redownloading it from the [torproject website](https://torproject.org).

If it still not works, see [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-installer-integrity-check-has-failed-common/c2e96749-6181-487c-80ec-3a0e24c32325) question.